# How to increment the Object in a Range of a For Each loop - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a For Each loop where I am trying to skip a Cell in the Range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopItems()

    Dim rRange As Range, oCell As Object

    'Set range of For Each loop
    Set rRange = Range("e2:e700")
    
    For Each oCell In rRange
    If IsEmpty(oCell) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If oCell.Value = 2 then
        oCell = oCell + 2 'Trying to skip the next 2 cells
    End If

    Next oCell
End Sub
```

Obiously this didn't work, as it tried to add a value of 2 to the oCell object.  How would I leapfrog 2 oCell's while still within the For Each?

Comment: By definition, `For Each` cycles through ALL elements of a collection. Rather than try and 'move' the oCell 'pointer', why not simply keep track of how many oCells you need to skip before acting on the next one? For example, in your case above, you would skip the next 1 item (if 2 means 'the second one from here') or 2 items. Something like `If nSkipsLeft > 0 nSkipsLeft = nSkipsLeft - 1 Else _act_on_the_oCell_ EndIf`.

Comment: Or just don't include the cells in the range to start with.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what you want to skip, whether that cell with the value 2 and 2 next or just the next 2. And whether you also want to skip this blank cell testing or not.
But in any case, you should add a counter and modify it accordingly. Example below, match with what you really need.

```
Sub LoopItems()

    Dim rRange As Range, oCell As Object, counter As Long
    
    'Set range of For Each loop
    Set rRange = Range("e2:e700")
    
    For Each oCell In rRange
    If IsEmpty(oCell) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If counter > 0 Then
        counter = counter - 1
        GoTo NextGo
    End If
    If oCell.Value = 2 Then
        counter = 2
        GoTo NextGo    ' this line if you want to skip also the current cell
        'oCell = oCell + 2 'Trying to skip the next 2 cells
    End If
    
NextGo:
    Next oCell
End Sub
```